# google-apps-script what is the Exit command

Tags: google-apps-script

In my Google Apps Script, when I catch an error, I email a log of the error then I want to exit the script immediately.

I cannot find a command to immediately terminate the script (the equivalent of PHP's exit().  Please can someone tell me how to do this?

Thanks in advance 
Alec

Comment: return is the word...:-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Return only works if you have a single function without depth.
What you actually want is to throw an exception, and catch it (or not) in your top level function. As in throw new Error("ouch")

Answer (score 6):

If you want to finish to run your function use

```
 return;
```